# Display freezes temporarily with nvidia drivers on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, display, freeze

I'm having a problem with my ubuntu 14.04 LTS laptop, with nvidia drivers. Every so often the display freezes. There doesn’t seem to be any pattern to it and the computer keeps running fine. I can unfreeze it by switching to a different virtual terminal and then back again. There seems nothing relevent about it in either the dmesg log or the lightdm logs.

Comment: Which version of the driver did you install? Did you use the 'Additional Drivers' utility or did you download the driver from the nvidia website?

Comment: I'm using nvidia-331-updates, I think through the additional drivers utility?

Comment: Oh, I thought it might have to do with a new nvidia driver which is not in the repository yet... 

Do you know if a process hangs when this happens (you could run 'top' in the virtual terminal)? However, this seems to be unlikely since switching to a virtual terminal fixes it...

Comment: There is this in dmesg, but its probably not related: [297221.800557] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About a year after I posted this question, and after testing on other linux distros including Kubuntu, I can now confidently say that the Nvidia drivers were not the issue: disabling intel proprietary microcode drivers solves the problem.